# Howto create and run a list of type TestClass(with different ctor-props) and run it

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a TestClass called `ActivityTestsFor27Jun` and `ActivityTestsFor13Sep`. These classes contain 6 TestMethods. I have a base class which set-up some things. They share a ton of the same vars. The only different vars are `month`, `day` of type `int` and `sunset` of type `DateTime`.

What I want to build is a TestClass called `ActivityTest` which takes 3 params in his constructor: `month`, `day`, `sunset`

Now I want to make some kind of a start class where I can do this

```
List<ActivityTest> activityTestList = new List<ActivityTest>();
activityList.add(new ActivityTest(6, 27, sunsetVal1));//27 jun
activityList.add(new ActivityTest(9, 13, sunsetVal2));//13 sep
activityList.add(new ActivityTest(x3, y3, sunsetVal3));// and so on..
```

And now something like `Run(activityTestList);`

A link to point me the way is also appreciated!

Comment: Please read about delegates - basically they are pointers to functions, which lets them to be treated like normal objects - you can pass them as function parameters

Comment: The only way I can do it now is to copy-paste the entire class. Change the 3 vars and run it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. What is ActivityTest? Is it the base class for ActivityTestsFor27Jun and ActivityTestsFor13Sep? What's the relationship between your classes? Also, if you try running what you have, what happens and how is it different from what you want?

Comment: ActivityTestFor27Jun and ActivityTestsFor13Sep are 2 different classes which are however totally identical except for the vars `month`, `day` and `sunset`. ActivityTest must became just like these classes except that is takes in 3 params in his c-tor. ActivityTest must replace ActivityTestFor27Jun  and ActivityTestFor13Sep

Comment: You can compare with a class called PersonBob and PersonJoe to be replaced with a class called Person and which takes a name param in his c-tor. I know how to loop through a list of type Person but not how to loop and executed through a list of type ActivityTest(where ActivityTest is marked as a TestClass and the methods inside as TestMethods)